# relations OneToMany - ManyToOne return null typeorm

Tags: json, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I made a relationship between two tables that it has: Users and Tasks.
according to the Typeorm ducommentation

Models:

```
 @Entity('tasks')
class Tasks {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column({
    type: 'varchar',
  })
  status: tasksStatus;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, user => user.tasks)
  user: User;

  @Column()
  description: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  created_at: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updated_at: Date;
}

@Entity('users')
class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @OneToMany(() => Tasks, task => task.user)
  tasks: Tasks[];

  @Column({
    unique: true,
  })
  email: string;

  @Column()
  password: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  created_at: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updated_at: Date;
}
```

Repositories:

```
public async findAll(): Promise<Tasks[]> {
    return this.ormRepository.find({ relations: ['user'] });
  }

public async findByAll(): Promise<User[]> {
    return this.ormRepository.find({
      relations: ['tasks'],
    });
  }
```

when I try to get a get, to get the user's listing, along with the tasks created by that user. the column value is null

and if i do a get on tasks it returns me user as null

```
[
  {
    "id": "91d9c552-64e7-4f64-b6e8-b8cfc9c6323a",
    "name": "teste do teste",
    "status": "NEW",
    "description": "testeteste do testeteste do testeteste do teste",
    "created_at": "2021-04-16T11:23:01.144Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-04-16T11:23:01.144Z",
    "user": null
  }
]




[ {
    "id": "ba2673a6-1d76-4294-98d1-3dc4556733d7",
    "name": "Wesley9",
    "email": "wesley19@email.com",
    "password": "$2a$08$xTprPchGJj3vy3vRfa2P2OWHn5V.hqMh8gQn7323J1wi7WjeWXzbG",
    "created_at": "2021-04-16T11:22:28.617Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-04-16T11:22:28.617Z",
    "tasks": []
  }
]
```

Comment: It seems that you have defined the relationship between user and task properly, I request you to provide a query generated by ORM and records which are there in database

Comment: The information in the DB and generate ORM is correct.

Comment: In your database connection options, add `logging: true` and check the query that is being generated when you make the query. I agree with @Soham Lawar and I suggest you check the database and verify that your records are properly referenced using foreign keys.

Comment: I managed to make the one to many / many to one relationship. thanks for all

Comment: @WesleyIsrael how? please post solution

Answer (score 0):

try this in your relations:

```
return this.ormRepository.find({ relations: {user: true });
```